# How to know if my iOS app has the correct Bundle ID?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I was trying to enable Push Notifications in my iOS app but it does not work because of some error like `"Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 « aps-environment ».`

After some research it may be because of Bundle ID and App ID stuff. Here is the situation:

In the Member Center in iTunes Connect, I have an App ID named "com.mysociety.mywebsitename" which I used to get the certificates to use Push Notifications.

In Xcode, in the General pane of my app project it says that the Bundle ID is "com.mysociety.mywebsitename.appname-", and the app name is in grey color and can't be erased. I don't know why the "appname-" part has been added. Does it mean that my Bundle ID is not correct and that it doesn't match the App ID in the Member Center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change / hardcode the bundle ID to "com.mysociety.mywebsitename" in your application's info.plist file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried but it didn't solve my problem. Do you know if I have to do what you suggest and make my Bundle identifier match the App id or if my Bundle Identifier is normal?

Comment: Are you using a wildcard (*) Provisioning Pofile? They won't work for push notifications. Go to your developer portal and make sure that everything is setup according to apple's specs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringPushNotifications/ConfiguringPushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH32-SW1

Comment: I don't use a wildcard. I did check that link but I didn't find a solution.